# How to save the result of my API call to my redux store, and call my API when my component firsts loads?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

So I created a react redux toolkit app and I am trying to play with the redux and actions.

I have a simple react component that looks like this:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../../app/hooks';
import {
  setBoard,
  fetchBoardAsync,
  selectBoard
} from './boardSlice';
import styles from './Board.module.css';

export function Board() {
  const board = useAppSelector(selectBoard);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();

  console.log(JSON.stringify(board));

  return (
    <div>
      <div className={styles.row}>
        <h3>Board</h3>
       
        <button
          className={styles.asyncButton}
          onClick={() => dispatch(fetchBoardAsync(""))}
        >
          Fetch board Data from API
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

When I click the button, it fetches some JSON - but right now it is just hard coded json variable.

```
// A mock function to mimic making an async request for data
export function fetchBoard() {
    return new Promise<{ data: any }>((resolve) =>
      setTimeout(() => resolve({ data: boardJson} ), 50)
    );
  }
```

where boardJson is simply:

```
let boardJson = { .... }
```

My boardSlice looks like:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import { RootState, AppThunk } from '../../app/store';
import { fetchBoard } from './boardAPI';

export interface BoardState {
  board: any;
  status: 'idle' | 'loading' | 'failed';
}

const initialState: BoardState = {
  board: {},
  status: 'idle',
};

export const fetchBoardAsync = createAsyncThunk(
  'board/fetchBoard',
  async (boardId: string) => {
    const response = await fetchBoard();
    console.log('fetch board returned data...' + JSON.stringify(response.data));
    return response.data;
  }
);

export const boardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'board',
  initialState,
  // The `reducers` field lets us define reducers and generate associated actions
  reducers: {
      setBoard: (state, action: PayloadAction<any>) => {
          state.board = action.payload;
      }
  },
```

I have 2 questions.

#1

When I click the button and it fetches the board, how do I save the result to my redux state?

#2
Also, in my Board component, how can I run fetchBoard when the component loads instead of having to click a button to trigger it? (this used to be a component lifecycle event like componentDidMount I think)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When I click the button and it fetches the board, how do I save the result to my redux state?

Your `boardSlice` reducer *almost* does what you expect. In the reducers field, you have provided an object of key/reducer values. Redux is unable to associate the key `setBoard` with the action created by `fetchBoardAsync`. If you were to `dispatch({ type: 'setBoard', payload })` then you would see your reducer fire as expected. Notice how the type is identical to the reducer key.

[`createAsyncThunk` example from Redux documentation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk)

[Matching utilities in RTK](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/matching-utilities)

Instead, you can use RTK builder syntax and matchers for the desired result:

```js
export const boardSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'board',
  initialState,
  extraReducers(builder) {
    builder.addCase(fetchBoardAsync.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.board = action.payload;
    })
  },
};
```

> #2 Also, in my Board component, how can I run fetchBoard when the component loads instead of having to click a button to trigger it? (this used to be a component lifecycle event like componentDidMount I think)

In a functional component, most React developers use the React hook `useEffect` for managing side-effects in a similar fashion to `componentDidMount`/`componentWillMount` and `componentWillUnmount`. [The documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useeffect) provides a lot of clarity on all the ways developers can leverage this hook.

For example:

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

import { useAppSelector, useAppDispatch } from '../../app/hooks';
import {
  setBoard,
  fetchBoardAsync,
  selectBoard
} from './boardSlice';
import styles from './Board.module.css';

export function Board() {
  const board = useAppSelector(selectBoard);
  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(fetchBoardAsync(""))
  }, []); // an empty dependency array tells React to only run the effect after mount

  console.log(JSON.stringify(board)); // may not have loaded yet

  return (
    <div>
      {/* snip */}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Once dispatched, thunks receive a second parameter for additional Redux functionality. A traditional thunk, which is the result of dispatching a function, receives redux API with this signature:

```js
function fetchBoardAsync() {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
    // now you can dispatch even more actions!
    // I don't believe this is necessary for your current use-case, but this is helpful for complicated side-effects in many apps
  }
}
```

[Redux thunk documentation](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk)

When using `createAsyncThunk`, the signature is this:

```js
function fetchBoardAsync(arg, api) {
  const { dispatch, extra, fulfillWithValue, getState, rejectWithValue, requestId, signal } = api;
}
```

[createAsyncThunk signature](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#payloadcreator)

Remember, you must still dispatch the thunk (either a function or the return value of `createAsyncThunk`) itself before you can use dispatch *inside* the thunk callback.

Comment: thanks, just reading up on the links you sent!   curious, if I was to do it the manual way and call dispatch, how do I get the dispatch function available from inside of my fetchBoardAsync  function?

Comment: @Blankman I expanded the answer to include details about how redux thunk middleware works. I hope it helps! If the answer is helpful, I'd be appreciative if you accepted it.

Comment: thanks, btw, since I am using redux, there is no point using the useState hook right?  b/c all state should be in redux anyhow....

Comment: @Blankman That's a matter of personal preference. If the state is specific to one component, and the state's value is not needed after the component unmounts, then it's not antipattern to use `useState.` If you find yourself inventing elaborate methods to pass `useState` values around your app, it might be worth using a redux store instead. My general "rule of thumb" is temporary UI state, e.g. form values, can be component state. If the value is shared between components, I put it in a redux store.

Comment: ok I updated my code, looks like there is some kind of infinit loop or something.   When I load my page, it just keeps repeately loading the board over and over again (my console.log just keeps outputing the sentence `fetch board returned data...`

Comment: @Blankman I'd need to see an example of the code to help

Comment: ok I was missing the `[]` that only runs the effect after mount!

Comment: @Blankman Big difference! No dependency array means run every render, empty array means only run after mount. I'm glad you got it solved.

Comment: that is a strange design decision they made to differentiate between those 2 behaviours...